# check to see if number ends in .00 using php

Tags: php

I'm working on something in zen cart and I don't want .00 to display on prices.
I thought I fixed the issue by doing

```
$price=number_format($special_price,2,'.','');
```

but zen cart has a function that adds the required currency symbol to the front or back of the number

```
$currencies->format($price)
```

The problem is that this function adds the .00 back onto the value!

The code for the function is

```
$format_string = $this->currencies[$currency_type]['symbol_left'] . number_format(zen_round($number * $rate, $this->currencies[$currency_type]['decimal_places']), $this->currencies[$currency_type]['decimal_places'], $this->currencies[$currency_type]['decimal_point'], $this->currencies[$currency_type]['thousands_point']) . $this->currencies[$currency_type]['symbol_right'];
```

If I duplicate that function so that I have $currencies->format2($price)  and change it to

```
$format_string = $this->currencies[$currency_type]['symbol_left'] . number_format(zen_round($number * $rate, $this->currencies[$currency_type]['decimal_places']), $this->currencies[$currency_type]['0'], $this->currencies[$currency_type]['decimal_point'], $this->currencies[$currency_type]['thousands_point']) . $this->currencies[$currency_type]['symbol_right'];
```

then it will add the currency symbol without adding the decimal places back in. Of course, when you have a price such as 49.50 it is then rounding this up to 50

I did try

```
    $cur_price=$currencies->format($special_price);
    $price=str_replace(".00", "", (string)number_format ($cur_price, 2, ".", ""));
```

The thinking behind it being that I could apply the currencies symbol first and then remove the decimals if they were .00, but that resulted in a blank space where the price should be.

I either need to find a way to check if

```
$price
```

ends in .00 so i can conditionally call $currencies->format() or $currencies->format2(), or I need to modify the original function to not put the decimal in place if it's .00, but allow it at all other times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would

```
$price = substr($price, -3) == ".00" ? substr($price, 0, -3) : $price;
```

work?

Comment: could round the number to two decimal places first?

Comment: @Tyler Sebastian, Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's explode() function to split the price into two parts (the part before and after the decimal), then check to see if it's what you want.

Try running the code below, then run it again after changing the `$curr_price` to something ending in 00.

```
<?php 
$curr_price = '45.99';
$price_array = explode('.', $curr_price);
if ($price_array[1] == '00')
{
    $curr_price = $price_array[0];
}
echo 'The price is ' . $curr_price . "<br>";
?>
```